# Why when I startActivityForResult in order to select image from gallery and I select an image, app is offering me source to choose from again

Tags: android

Application starts and prompts me to select image source, I choose gallery, click on selected image, gallery is stopped but I am prompted again to choose image source instead to be directed to the activity that will show image I choosed.

What is happening here, do I need to stop this intent somehow? Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // WIDGETS
    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 10;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_PHOTO);

        /*Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);    */

    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceivingActivity.class);
                Cropper cropper = new Cropper(this, this, intent, selectedImage);

                cropper.setCropperCornerImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                cropper.setCropperStrokeColor(R.color.pickante_blue);       
                cropper.setOptionBarColor(R.color.pickante_blue);
                cropper.setActionBuffer(20);

                cropper.setUpCropper(layout);               

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onActivityResult()`;

Comment: Are you setting `noHistory` for this activity in your manifest? because it seems MainActivity is not in backstack and its calling onCreate() again.

Comment: No I'm not. It's strange because on Genymotion emulated S3 works fine but on real device it prompts me to select image source again but behind I can see that ImageView is populated with selected image...

Comment: can you post logcat message after selecting image? can you debug and check `onActivityResult`?

Comment: That's the problem, I can't debug real device because I'm at work and laptop here has problems with drivers for Samsung, so I'm exporting apk and test it on my phone. But at the same time I can't debug on emulator since everything works fine there... fubar

Comment: Use google-usb-driver. I guess its a memory issue. Try picking some smaller size photo from gallery.